# Possible Circular Package Dependency - XSLT 3.0

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I'm trying xsl:package for the first time but getting an error on the command line-

xml (not really used)-

```
<woot/>
```

package.xsl-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:package name="http://example.org/package.xsl"
    package-version="1.0"  version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:f="http://example.org/package">

    <xsl:function name="f:woot" visibility="public">
        <xsl:value-of select="'DANGGGG'"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:package>
```

package-use.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:package name="http://example.org/package-use.xsl"
    package-version="1.0"  version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:f="http://example.org/package">

    <xsl:use-package name="http://example.org/package.xsl" package-version="1.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="output-text" select="f:woot()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$output-text"/>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:package>
```

On command line (using saxon 9.7)

```
> java -jar saxon9ee.jar woot.xml package-use.xsl;package.xsl
```

returns-

**Possible circular package dependency**

I tried similar transformation on Oxygen XML with Saxon 9.6 and got java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

I've logged a Saxon bug here:

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2541

I'm afraid that until we issue a patch there's no workaround other than running the transformation from the s9api API rather than from the command line.

You will hit another issue when you get past this one: your package needs to declare the modes it uses. Adding an empty `<xsl:mode/>` declaration is the minimum fix.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and also pointing out the mode issue. Looking forward to the next release.